# Круглый progress bar с анимацией

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

Пытаюсь сделать круглый progress bar. Идея такая, что progress - служит фоном, а secondaryProgress отображает само значение.

Код из layout:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:id="@+id/myProgress"
        android:progress="100"
        android:secondaryProgress="60"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbarstyle"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:max="100" />
```

Код progressbarstyle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="90" android:toDegrees="90" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%">
            <shape android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5" android:shape="ring" android:thicknessRatio="40.0" >
                <gradient android:centerColor="@color/colorItemBg" android:endColor="@color/colorItemBg"
                    android:startColor="@color/colorItemBg" android:type="sweep" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="90" android:toDegrees="90" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%">
            <shape android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5" android:shape="ring" android:thicknessRatio="40.0">
                <gradient android:centerColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:endColor="@color/MainColor"
                    android:startColor="@color/MainColor" android:type="sweep" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

На превью отображается верно, но если запустить на телефоне, то всегда показывает 100%. В чем ошибка? И как добавить анимацию при изменении значения secondaryProgress?

Comment: Если вам нужен круглый, то вот эту строку `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"` надо бы убрать...

Comment: Если убрать эту строчку, то он начинает постоянно крутиться и не показывает нужное значение.

Comment: А если так поставить: `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleNormal"`?

Comment: Нет такого атрибута. Пробовал сделать Small, но тоже самое.

Comment: У меня не полуилось заставить работать приведённый вам код. Скорее всего он работает только на старых версиях (если вообще работает). Так что вам надо просто взять одну из множества библиотек для решения вашей задачи, вместо попыток заставить сей костыль работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27269329/3212712) можно заменить содержимое вашего `progressbarstyle.xml` на вот это и оно будет работать:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="3.8sp"
    android:useLevel="true">
    <solid android:color="@color/material_red_500"/>
</shape>
```

Также, по ссылке помянуто как это заставить работать на API<21 и как анимировать.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Все работает, если для shape задать свойство `android:useLevel="true"`.

Comment: Пожалуй стоит добавить, что сей аттрибут, видимо, нужен на `API>=21`.